# Is there CSS which can allow an element to follow flow, while a child has position:absolute?

Tags: html, css

Is there CSS which can allow an element to follow flow (similar to position:inline), while a child to the element has position:absolute?

EDIT: the answer is yes, just use inline and position absolute. I had a different issue than the one I posted. My apologies. My issue was that using margin:auto made the item centred, but gave all margins 0 rather than the maximum amount (ie. the container would spread as far as it could and the border would generally touch the border of the parent element). To solve the issue I'll be using an additional container and text-align.

Thanks to the people who helped and read this question.

Ignore the following historic portion of the post.

> Obviously I want the position absolute to be positioned relative to
>   the bounds of it's parents (so the parent would *not* have
>   position:static).
>
> Still I am unsure how to do this. Does CSS even have the expressive
>   power to do this?
>
> Think of having a picture in the middle of a paragraph, but instead of
>   an image, it's a container with more elements inside.

Comment: "positioned relative to..." There's your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is `position:relative;`

Position relative retains the normal flow position but allows coordinate modifications. Using the css values top and left, for example will move the object relative to where it should normally be placed. If you nest the object inside a `div`, it will use the `div`'s top left corner as the 0,0 coordinate origin.

Keep in mind that the `position:relative` property is applied to the elements inside your parent container and not the parent itself. You can use static or whatever you'd like for the parent. However, the parent won't necessarily resize to encapsulate its relatively positioned children visually, so you will have to set height and width values yourself.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #my_button {
        position:relative;
        top:10px;
        left:10px
    }
    #my_div {
        height:25px;
        background-color:yellow
    }
</style>

<div id="my_div">
    <input type="button" value="OK" id="my_button"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like the parent to follow flow, like an inline element, allowing it's siblings to be beside it, unlike a div which is display:block and therefore clears the left and right.

Comment: For the parent, what you are looking for is display:inline-block. inline-block flows normally but allows you to set a height to your parent object so that you'll be able to properly contain your relatively positioned child objects. This has some good information on inline-block. http://vivifystudios.com/articles-css-inline-block/

Comment: I think I must have messed something else up. I created an isolated test and absolute worked fine in an inline element. Thanks for the answer, sorry for the confusion.
I'll try it against in my more complicated example and if I figure out my pitfall I'll post it back on my question.
I won't post a question again without isolating first -_-.

Answer (score 0):

Use position:relative; That way the parent stays in the same location but child elements with position: absolute are positioned relative to the parent not the body.

Comment: That works fine when the parent is display:block, but if I want the parent to be display:inline, then the position:absolute doesn't work right.

Comment: Could you use display:inline-block for the parent?